# DHCP Relay for two L3 EX2200 Juniper (How many relays?)

Tags: routing, vlan, juniper, juniper-ex

I came accross this tutorial:

```
Topology:

[Client PC] --- ge-0/0/0 [EX Switch] ge0/0/1 --- [DHCP Server]

Client PC is in VLAN 10.

The DHCP server is in VLAN 20 with the 20.20.20.2 IP address.

The EX switch is configured as DHCP relay and performs inter VLAN routing between VLANs 10 and 20.

Configuration:
set vlans vlan10 vlan-id 10
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members vlan10
set vlans vlan10 l3-interface vlan.10
set interfaces vlan unit 10 family inet address 10.10.10.1/24

set vlans vlan20 vlan-id 20
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members vlan20
set interfaces vlan unit 20 family inet address 20.20.20.1/24
set vlans vlan20 l3-interface vlan.20
set forwarding-options helpers bootp server 20.20.20.2
set forwarding-options helpers bootp interface vlan.10

Note: VLAN.10 Routed VLAN Interface (RVI) is configured for bootp relay, so that bootp packets in VLAN 10 will be routed to the '20.20.20.2' server in VLAN 20. Configure the specific RVIs, to which the bootp packets should be forwarded. A separate server can be configured under the 'bootp interface vlan.X' stanza for only that specific VLAN. A global server IP can also be specified (as above), which is applicable for all RVI interfaces.
```

I have a similar setup, except that instead of two vlans on the same switch, I have two switches connected together using OSPF. In my code I am using the same setup, but I'm wondering, how many relays will I need. One at each switch, or just one on the switch without the dhcp server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only need one for each VLAN. Basically where you configure the dhcp relay (IP helper) on your VLAN interface, the switch will forward the DHCP request to the IP helper you have provided. This will become unicast traffic and get routed to the DHCP server which should be the IP address you have set in **set forwarding-options helpers bootp server 20.20.20.2**.

If 20.20.20.2 is reachable, it won't matter how many hops it is away. Just make sure you have a route path going back. It won't work if the DHCP server can't reach the client that is requesting an IP address from the DHCP server and sometimes people forget that you need a route both directions.

So to summarize:

Set DHCP relay configuration for each vlan that does not reside on the same subnet (even across internet) as the DHCP server. The configuration only needs to be set on the switch/router that is being used as the gateway. You do not need to set the configuration on edge switches or any switches that come after your gateway.

Hope this helps you on your quest.

SleepyMan